Can I use a named range as column headers?
I have a named range TheSuspects with 3 names: Jimmy, Jackie, and Doug.
On another sheet I want to use these names as part of a header row, for example like this:

Is there a way to do this? As far as I know, formulas with multiple values always return vertically instead of horizontally.
My actual use case is more complicated. The list of names may have frequent edits and several other sheets need to reflect those edits, preferably without manual work. The names will be used in both columns and rows.

For horizontal layout;
=transpose(TheSuspects)



So simple! Thanks!

You're welcome, you can accept the post as an Answer if you care...
